# Display a value in table when meeting a condition

Tags: java, swing

I need to show in my jTable the value of `Admin` when an `account_type` is `1` and `Cashier` if it is `2`. Please help me.. here is my snippet:

```
    private void Update_table() {
        try{

    String sql = "SELECT idno as 'User ID', username as 'Username', password as 'Password', account_type as 'Account_Type' from user";

    st = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);


   while(rs.next())
   {
    if(rs.getInt(4)==1)
    {
        rs.updateString(4, "1");

    }
    viewUserTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    viewUserTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

    viewUserTable.setSelectionMode(SINGLE_SELECTION);
    viewUserTable.setAutoResizeMode(5);
   }
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what you're trying to do, or what doesn't work.

Comment: That falls into the domain of the `TableCellRenderer`, [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)